# Changing only Application ID, not package name

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I only want to change application id in gradle file, but dont want to change package name.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 17):

It is not recommended to change your application id. What you can do is change your application suffix.

As an example, if your application id is **com.example.my_app** then add different suffixes for different build types, such as **com.example.myapp.dev** for debug.

Go to **app/build.gradle** file and on **android** block add the suffix you want:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ".production"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants)

Answer (score 0):

No problem. You can change your application Id as long as your app is not on store. If you change your application id, It would immediately become a different app for google play.

I have many apps with different package name and application ids.

Comment: i have two app and they copy of each other. when i only change application ids and try to download from store, i getting this error "INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER" but now i solve it. also need to add android:authorities="${applicationId}" its solve my problem..

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change `androidId` in `defaultConfig`.

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.somepkg" // <- we can change applicationId in defaultConfig
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26

            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            ....
        }
}
```

Also we can change `applicationId` in flavors use suffix or override it:

```
flavorDimensions "app"
productFlavors {
        qa {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".qa" // <- add suffix (it will be )
        }
        production {
            applicationId = "com.someotherpkg" // <- we can change applicationId in flavors
            dimension "app"
        }
}
```

However your src files will be still in the same folders.