# Change application ID for Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I change my application id as part of my build process depending on the build type ([Changing only Application ID, not package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082195/changing-only-application-id-not-package-name)). However my Fabric crashes are all going to the same app. I suppose this is because Fabric looks at what is defined in the `AndroidManifest` and not what is in `build.gradle`, but is there a way to change this programmatically?

I see a `crashlytics.injectingBuildId` which might be relevant but I have no clue what this does (or where I can find docs around this).

Comment: Thanks. We do not have a documented solution for this. We use the package name to identify the app. Are you changing the package name before or after the Crashlytics section of the build.gradle?

Comment: It's before the Crashlytics section in the file, but it is evaluated after the Crashlytics section.