# How to install two versions of the same Android app on one (rooted) device?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

Is it possible to install two instances of the same app on a rooted Android device?

I know, that the Android system distinguishes apps based on their package name.
It is possible to decompile apps with tools like `apktool`, change the Manifest file and recompile / sign them. However, for more sophisticated applications (e.g., if they have multiple `apk` files packed in a `apkx` file) or complex dependencies this not always works.

I do not want to work with third party applications like Dual Space, Titanium Backup and so on.

How would you approach this?

Comment: i'm pretty sure adding an application prefix or suffix allows you to have 2 of the "same" apps installed, even on a non-rooted device

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082195/changing-only-application-id-not-package-name

Comment: @a_local_nobody When I am the developer myself it is easy, but we are talking about arbitrary apps e.g., from the PlayStore

Comment: ahh i see, in that case i'm not sure you'll find answers here, this might be more of a generic hw/sw issue then, perhaps you can find an answer on the android SE ?  https://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Use lucky patcher's "clone" function in the tools menu (shouldn't be hard to find)
2. Copy the app apk out of system memory and edit it manually (good luck, text file "readers" read it fine, editors do not)
3. Use an apk editor to change the package name (I have a copy of one if necessary)